# Unity google play plugin issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

I'm trying to add google play service plugin to my game.
after 10 hours of constant work I cant seem to find a solution to the following issue.
 when reading the logs I get a "this application ID is not associated with the package name com.bla.bla"
Going into my console on google dev you can easily see that it is linked and the something else is causing the issue... I used the keytool to check the fingerprint certificated SHA1 and its the same both in the APK file and the google play console.
 
Might be relevant to note that I'm using the most up to date plugin and it generates the AndroidManifest.XML by itself so there isn't much place to make mistakes there, and by the log's request I can see that its actually asking for the correct package..

I honestly have no idea what else I can do to fix this, I've literally tried EVERYTHING.
Open to any suggestion possible.

Comment: Which logs? Logcat from the app running on your device?

Comment: Solving my own issue, it appears that if you do not release a version and only use an Alpha test, only the people defined as Testers on the google console (via Emails) can connect to the google play via the application, the error given is so misleading ! hope it helps anyone in the future !

Comment: Add your solution as an answer. Then mark it as the correct answer two days from now when the timer expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if you do not release a version and only use an Alpha test, only the people defined as testers on the google console (using their emails) can connect to the google play via the application, the error given is so misleading! Personally I was using a certain google account as a tester and my phone was set to use a different google account to log in to google play so it would terminate the connection every time!

Hope this helps future problems.